# Is there a way to set the formatting of all text in a figure using one command?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I make figures in matplotlib, I generally want to make all of the text matching in format (e.g. axis labels, legend, axis ticks), as bold and size 20.  Is there a way to do this in one command rather than having to specify it on every text instance?

What I'm looking for is something that will change this:

```
    fig, ax = plt.figure()
    ax.set_title("Title", fontsize = 20, fontweight = 'bold')
    plt.xlabel("xlabel", fontsize = 20, fontweight = 'bold')
    plt.ylabel("ylabel", fontsize = 20, fontweight = 'bold')
    plt.xticks(fontsize = 20, fontweight = 'bold')
    plt.yticks(fontsize = 20, fontweight = 'bold')
```

To something more like this, without affecting the output:

```
    fig, ax = plt.figure()
    alltextformat = fontsize = 20, fontweight = 'bold'
    ax.set_title("Title")
    plt.xlabel("xlabel")
    plt.ylabel("ylabel")
    plt.xticks()
    plt.yticks()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you want to change your [`rcParams`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rcParams). One way is like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-10, 10)
y = x ** 2
with plt.rc_context(rc={'font.size': 20, 'font.weight': 'bold'}):
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

or for the whole session

```
plt.rc('font', size=20, weight='bold')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

#### Edit

See also: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html